# How to submit a Contact Form without sending email?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have Contact Form 7 and Contact Form DB installed on my WordPress site, but don't and don't want to have a mail server. At this moment, I can collect form information from Contact Form DB, so is there any ways to disable the mailing function of a submit button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding this into the **`Additional Settings`** section makes it stop mailing.
[image]

```
demo_mode: on
```

Comment: Although this works, it can cause problems for other plugin integrations so it's more advisable to use the `skip_mail: on` setting or use a filter as-per @ado_dev and @Duy Hoang

Answer (score 4):

Add this code to your plugin or functions.php

`add_filter('wpcf7_skip_mail', 'yourname_wpcf7_skip_mail');`
`function yourname_wpcf7_skip_mail()`
`{`
`return true;`
`}`

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

There may have been some changes. For example, on current version setting `demo_mode: on` will result in database not being filled with forms.
Use `skip_mail: on` instead.

From the official website:

> The skip_mail setting works in the almost same
>   manner as the demo_mode, but the skip_mail skips the mail sending
>   only. Unlike demo_mode, skip_mail doesn’t affect other activities like
>   storing messages with Flamingo.

Source:
https://contactform7.com/additional-settings/